# Saving pip installs in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to save packages in Google Collab to my Google Drive?  This is so I won't have to re-download and re-install packages every time I want to use them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To save your the installed configuration to your Google Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
pip freeze --local > /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/colab_installed.txt
```

To restore from drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall `cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/colab_installed.txt`
```

Comment: This solution does not remove the necessity to _"to re-download and re-install packages every time"_, it simply saves the names and versions of installed packages into a text file.

Comment: So the question is still open (for 3 years), does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: @DudiFrid I have not tried it yet but this answer seems to answer a similar question and has a lot of upvotes : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55253499/19955621