# Google Colab Project : saving installed packages to virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, google-colaboratory

After the project have been working, is there a way to save the required dependencies and packages of the script to a virtualenv ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving pip installs in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582858/saving-pip-installs-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pre-canned way to do this.
You can run `!pip freeze` to note installed packages / versions, which may help you recreate the environment you want. If that's insufficient can you say more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried !pip freeze, but it contained a list of install packages of colab but many were not required in my project. I want to put the project into a flask web.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with flask web but maybe what you want is to store the diff between `!pip freeze` right after resetting your runtimes (so you have a "clean" VM) and the output of `!pip freeze` after your setup cell is complete?