# How to save installed modules in colab?

Tags: python-3.x, module, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, savestate

There is a problem whenever I install a module in google-colab like speechrecognition module,
it works perfectly but then if I open a new tab of colab or open colab again after closing it,
it doesn't import the speechrecognition module, because every time i open a colab environment,
it is completely a fresh environment so I have to install all my required modules again.
is there any way to save it as a checkpoint so that I don't have to install it again and again.

*I know we can save models to google drive but I have to save modules*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving pip installs in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582858/saving-pip-installs-in-google-colab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

Answer (score 1):

```
# first install gcsfuse
%%capture
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt update
!apt install gcsfuse


 next

import os, sys
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
nb_path = '/content/notebooks'
os.symlink('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks', nb_path)
sys.path.insert(0,nb_path)

#you can install module with below format
!pip install --target=$nb_path [module_name]
#verify with below format
import module_name
```