# How to update to the latest version of sklearn in colab notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am a beginner in machine learning. I am using colab as the primary development platform.
I would like to use the latest version of sklearn in my coding projects. However, colab's sklearn version is 0.22.

Can I update the scikit learn version in colab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- You mentioned that you have a 0.22 version, hopefully, you checked and received the following results (by default) in your colab notebook.

  ```
  !pip list | grep scikit-learn

  scikit-learn 0.22.2.post1
  ```
- I presume that you already tried with the following command, which ideally installs the latest version of sckit-learn.

  ```
  !pip install scikit-learn

  Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.22.2.post1)
  Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.5)
  Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.1)
  Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.4.1)
  ```
- As per the latest scikit-learn [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html), 0.24.2 is the latest version, which you can install/upgrade by overriding the version number as shown in the following script. It should help you if you want to upgrade to 0.24.2.

  ```
  !pip install scikit-learn==0.24.2
  ```
- Then, verify the scikit-learn version by following script.

  ```
  !pip list | grep scikit-learn

  scikit-learn 0.24.2
  ```
- Also, alternative way to upgrade the package in a colab environment.

  ```
  !pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
  ```

Ideally, you'll need to install it each time, however, some workaround such as you can save the current configuration into your google drive. Refer to the following script which was suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582858/saving-pip-installs-in-google-colab).

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
pip freeze --local > /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/colab_installed.txt
```

Refer to the following script to restore the environment from the file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall `cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/colab_installed.txt`
```

Comment: I succeeded in updating the version of scikit-learn to 0.24.2 for the current notebook that I am using. Is it possible to propagate this version to all my notebooks as I realize that when I create a new notebook, I need to do the installation again. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, you'll need to install it each time.

Comment: However, added some other alternate approach in the response answer itself as the comment doesn't allow a long response.